# For the Following code,im getting a error InputMismatch exception,even when im providing correct input

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
class Person {
    public enum Sex {
        Male, Female
    }
    String Name;
    int Age;
    Sex Gender;
    String EmailAddress;
    public int getAge() {
        return Age;
    }
    static public Person getInstance() {
        return new Person();
    }
    public String getPerson() {
        return Name;
    }
}
public class TestPerson {
    public static void main(String...args) {
        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(Person.getInstance());
        list.add(Person.getInstance());
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System. in );
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i).Name = s.nextLine());
            System.out.println(list.get(i).Age = s.nextInt());
        }
        s.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Especially in the for loop!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Generics as Sir Eric said:

```
List<Person> = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

Also: When you are using `nextLine();` method after `nextInt();`,

the `nextLine();` will take **`"\n"`** as its input in **next iteration** because `nextInt();` only takes the next integer token and not the `Enter Button ("\n")`, which is then taken by `nextLine();` of next `iteration` in your `code` case.

Either use

- `Integer.parseInt(nextLine());` instead of `nextInt();`.

OR

- just skip the `"\n"` by using `nextLine();` like follows:

  ```
   public static void main(String...args) {
          List<Person> = new ArrayList<Person>();
          list.add(Person.getInstance());
          list.add(Person.getInstance());
          Scanner s = new Scanner(System. in );
          for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
              System.out.println(list.get(i).Name = s.nextLine());
              System.out.println(list.get(i).Age = s.nextInt());
              s.nextLine(); //skips the "\n" 
          }
          s.close();
      }
  ```

Comment: why is the problem of \n is arising in the loop,is that due to the println method?

Comment: no, as I said nextInt() will only take the next integer token. And we usually input a number and then press enter ("which is actually a new line - '\n'').... now nextLine() takes all input up to new line ( excluding '\n') . Hence in the next iteration will only contain - `""` . see here for more details - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods .

Answer (score 1):

You need to use generics when declaring your list.

```
List<Person> = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

Now the compiler knows that you intend to populate this list with your `Person` object, and not regular `Objects`. Without generics, it assumes the list will be populated with Objects, which don't have `Name` and `Age` as variables, thus the compiler complains.